# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't match url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, global

I uploaded a new website in a sub-folder of my server documentroot `(www.example.com/demos/website-name)` as I've always done to show demos to my clients.

In my cms I use `mod_rewrite` to push all requests to `index.php` and an "internal" rewrite in php, so I have to retrieve the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to read it and load the correct page.

Quite randomly (and only when the cms is placed in a subfolder like this case) the `REQUEST_URI` doesn't match the uri in the browser but remains the previous one: for example I'm in `"/cms/foo"`, i click a link that brings me to `"/cms/bar"`, the page reloads but if i dump the `REQUEST_URI` I still get `"/cms/foo"`.

I really can't understand how this is possible.

This is how the .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And here it is how I retrieve the `REQUEST_URI` (`MainConfig::ROOT_URL` is the sub-folder path "/demos/website-name"):

```
public static function getPath()
{
    if(isset(self::$cache['path'])) {
        return self::$cache['path'];
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $path = str_replace(MainConfig::ROOT_URL, '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        $path = explode('/', $path);
        if(trim($path[1]) == '') {
            $path = array();
        }
        unset($path[0]);
        $path = array_values($path);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($path); $i++) {
            $fragment = $path[$i];
            if(strpos($fragment, '?') !== false) {
                $lastPathIndex = $i;
                break;
            } elseif(strpos($fragment, 'index.php') !== false) {
                $lastPathIndex = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isset($lastPathIndex)) {
            $lastPathElement = array();
            $length = count($path);
            for($i = $lastPathIndex; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $lastPathElement[] = $path[$i];
                unset($path[$i]);
            }
            $lastPathElement = str_replace('index.php', '', implode('/', $lastPathElement));
        }
        if(isset($lastPathElement)) {
            $path[] = $lastPathElement;
        }
    } else {
        $path = array();
    }
    $path = array_values($path);
    self::$cache['path'] = $path;
    return $path;
}
```

Comment: If it only happens is a sub folder, it's not really random.

Comment: With "randomly" I mean that the problem is present only when the website is placed in a subfolder but not shows at any visited page but only sometimes... randomly!

Comment: Is `self::$cache['path']` stored for use in subsequent requests or just for the lifetime of one request?

Comment: Is stored for other requests, but I already tried removing it and the problem remained (and when you reload/change page it should return empty however... :/